# I want to know every single bit there is to understand in this following proof

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I'm ashamed of myself for not answering my professor when he asked if I found the proof myself. I gave him the impression that I did which was still not true. So I want to make it right.

It's about the proof of the product of the functions $f$ and $g$ is continuous. I found the proof [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/class255/08s1/01s2/H5.pdf), it's on the 1st page on the bottom of the page. 
I'd like to know why he/she starts with setting prerequisites like $\epsilon \lt 1$ and $M = \max(f(a), |g(a)|,1)$. I certainly don't understand why to put $M$ like that.

And the second sentence I understand because first of all it's defining what we already know about continuity and then setting an assumption,ok.

But then the inequality $f(x) \lt f(a) + \dfrac{\epsilon}{3M} \le M + \dfrac{\epsilon}{3M}$ Why exactly did he/she do that?

Thanks for making things right.

Comment: Trying to understand a proof is doing the right thing, but it does not make it right to have lied to your professor.

Comment: Yeah, I know I will tell him or show him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, note that $a$ is chosen beforehand, so you are allowed to use anything directly dependent on $a$. Now the inequality:
$$|(fg)(x) − (fg)(a)| \leq |f(x)||g(x) − g(a)| + |g(a)||f(x) − f(a)|$$
we are able to estimate $|f(x) − f(a)|$ and $|g(x) − g(a)|$ by $\varepsilon$, but to do this correctly, we must also absolve $|f(x)|$ and $|g(a)|$. Note that the latter one is a fixed number, since $a$ was chosen first. We need to estimate $|f(x)|$. This can be done by using the reverse triangle inequality: $||f(x)| − |f(a)||\leq |f(x) − f(a)|$, which implies that $|f(x)| − |f(a)|\leq |f(x) − f(a)|$ and thus $|f(x)|\leq|f(a)|+|f(x) − f(a)|$. We see that both can be estimated.

Now for the estimation:
we want some number greater than both $|f(a)|$ and $|g(a)|$ (so the multiplicative inverse is small), but also greater than $1$ to prevent dividing by $0$, so we can choose some $M=\max(|f(a)|, |g(a)|,1)$:
$$\color{red}{|f(x)|}|g(x) − g(a)| + \color{green}{|g(a)|}|f(x) − f(a)|< \color{red}{|f(x)|}\varepsilon + \color{green}{|g(a)|}\varepsilon\leq\color{red}{(M+\varepsilon)}\varepsilon+\color{green}{M}\varepsilon$$

Now of course we want this all estimated by only one $\epsilon$, so in the beginning he chooses $\varepsilon=\frac{\epsilon}{3M}$, where we include the $M$ to absolve the $M$'s and $3$ to cleanly estimate the three $\varepsilon$-terms. We see that
$$(M+\varepsilon)\varepsilon+M\varepsilon=\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{9M^2}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Now without loss of generality (because these proofs are always about small $\epsilon$'s) we let $\epsilon<1$ to cleanly estimate the middle term, so $$\frac{\epsilon^2}{9M^2}=\epsilon\frac{\epsilon}{9M^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{9M^2}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{9}$$
where we remember that $M\geq 1$, so $\frac{1}{M}\leq 1$.
And so we end up with
$$\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{9M^2}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}< \epsilon$$

I find his proof rather difficult. It can be done much easier.

Also, this looks like a lot, but later on you will get used to this kind of thinking (and everything turns trivial).

Comment: Oh, ok. I see it now. One shouldn't work in the way the author presented. First the inequality, then the estimation and at last you complete the puzzle.

Comment: And I like it when it is complex therefore I can ask myself more and more questions. It's like a labyrinth.

Comment: "we want this all estimated by only one $\epsilon$"?  I *don't* want this, especially during exams and in more advanced books.  Say, in the standard graduate [*Fourier Analysis*](http://prof.usb.ve/bueno/Libros/069111384X%20-%20Princeton%20University%20-%20Fourier%20Analysis~%20An%20Introduction%20-%20%282003%29.pdf) textbook written by *Stein*, the author won't bother to do so.  (c.f. Thm 4.1: the author wants to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f*K_n)(x) = f(x)$$, and his finishes the proof with $$|(f*K_n)(x) - f(x)|\le C\epsilon$$)

Comment: Although you are very careful about your symbology, so that it is literally correct, it may be worth pointing out for folks who inadvertently elide the difference that you are using two different variants of epsilon, $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$, with different meanings.

Answer (score 6):

I'm typing this for fun.  The question asks for explanation of the linked proof.  I'll first explain *the* proof, before using it to analyse *that* proof, so that OP knows the *role* of $M$, "$\epsilon<1$" and $\epsilon/3$ in that proof.

## Criticism of the linked proof

To understand elementary [epsilon-delta](/questions/tagged/epsilon-delta) proofs in [calculus](/questions/tagged/calculus), I *don't* follow the literal order--they are put in such way so as to get a *logically* correct answer.  Logically correct things may not be instructive to mathematicians, such as the proof of $1+1=2$ and the proof of Zorn's Lemma.

The use of $\epsilon/3$ in the linked proof is *not* suggested for students, especially in tests or exams.  You can easily mess up things under stress and pressure---It is *logically* fine to put $M\epsilon$, where $M$ is a *constant*.  This practice is common in more advanced math.  In fact, the author tries to change $M\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$.  This adds *no* rigors to the proof, but renders the arguments too complicated for revision and reading---this motivates me to give such criticism to that proof.

## Step-by-step explanation of *the* proof

Thinking from the reverse enables you to assimilate the proof, so that you can respond to similar questions in the future -- that's the fool-proof way.

1. Fix $\epsilon > 0$
2. Jump to $|(fg)(x)-(fg)(a)|<\epsilon$ skip the settings on $\delta$.  *This is our goal.*
3. Think about $f(x)\underset{x\to a}\longrightarrow f(a)$ and $g(x)\underset{x\to a}\longrightarrow g(a)$ in (vague) words: "when $x$ is near $a$, ...".  Use this to get $\delta' := \delta_f \wedge \delta_g$ so that you may use $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ and $|g(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon$ *at the same time*.  (Write $\delta_1,\delta_2$ if you want.)
4. To use the inequalities in step (3) to finish our goal in (2), we *need* to insert *either* $f(x)g(a)$ or $f(a)g(x)$.  WLOG, we stick with the author's choice: $f(x)g(a)$.
5. To balance the effect of (4), we put another $f(x)g(a)$ into LHS of (2) but with *opposite* sign, so that it becomes $|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(a)+f(x)g(a)-f(a)g(a)|$
6. From this, it's obvious that we have to apply the triangle inequality and factor out some terms to get $|f(x)||g(x) − g(a)| + |g(a)||f(x) − f(a)|$.
7. Apply (3): intuitively when $x$ is "near" $a$, $|f(x)|$ is "near" $|f(a)|$.  Draw a (vertical) straight line to see the geometric meaning of $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. (Distance between $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ is less than $\epsilon$.)  From this, we easily get $|f(x)|<|f(a)|+\epsilon$.  Then (6) is bounded above by \begin{align}
   & |f(x)||g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)| \\
   &\le (|f(a)|+|f(x)-f(a)|)|g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)| \\
   &= \color{blue}{|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)|} + \color{red}{|f(a)||g(x)-g(a)|} + |f(x)-f(a)| |g(x)-g(a)| \\
   &< (|f(a)|+\epsilon)\epsilon + |g(a)|\epsilon \\
   &= (|f(a)|+|g(a)|) \epsilon + \epsilon^2.
   \end{align}
8. *Intuitively* $\epsilon$ is "small", (so $\epsilon^2$ is even "smaller"), so we're "done".

   - *Logically* in (1), we have *for all* $\epsilon > 0$ in the very definition of limit, so we *can't* discard the square $^2$ by saying that $\epsilon^2 \le \epsilon$.  To *fix this logical* problem, we change (1) to $0 < \epsilon \le 1$.
   - Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary above, this doesn't affect the validity other established inequalities.  So the existence of $\delta$ responding to the question has been proven for the case $0 < \epsilon \le 1$.
   - If $\epsilon > 1$, apply the results proven for $\epsilon' = 1$: $$\forall\,\epsilon>1, \exists\,\delta > 0 \dots |\cdots| < 1 < \epsilon$$

## Explanation of *that* proof using *the* proof

As another answer points out, his professor want the RHS
$$ \color{blue}{\epsilon |g(a)|} + \color{red}{\epsilon |f(a)|}
+ \epsilon^2 $$
"all estimated by only *one*" $\epsilon$.  To do so, he set another "smaller" $\epsilon$ in step (3) (i.e $\epsilon$ divided a "large" number $M$), so that
$$\color{blue}{|f(x)-f(a)||g(a)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3} \iff |f(x)-f(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3|g(a)|}}$$
and
$$\color{red}{|g(x)-g(a)||f(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3} \iff |g(x)-g(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3|f(a)|}}$$
*if $f(a)\ne0$ and $g(a)\ne0$*.
We set $M \ge 1$ to fix this problem, so that $M = \max(|f(a)|,|g(a),1)$.  It's easy to check that $|f(x)-f(a)| |g(x)-g(a)| < \dfrac\epsilon3$.

## Final Remark: Comparison of my answer than the alternate answer

- The alternative answer uses the fact that $3\times3=9$, as in *that* proof.  Mine has marginally simpler arithmetic calulations: I only use $1+1=2$ and $1\times3=3$.
- My answer has more bullet points and numbered list.

Comment: It's not my professor's proof, the proof I provided is the proof of a professor in New-Zealand and I don't even live there.

Comment: @AnonymousI OK!  I'll edit that.  Anyways, it's about the unnecessary complexity of the linked proof.

Comment: I understand that, the only thing is that it seems whatever I go in exams I fail it. No matter what. Now I'm against my own will going over each single bit very carefully which makes me quite upset since I don't get enough time to watch a tv series or so.

Comment: @AnonymousI I suggest you watching TV first.  Paul Halmos says [*the only way to learn math is to do math*](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4w96zy/the_right_way_to_learn_maths_paul_halmos/).  If you don't feel motivated enough to do math, you won't work efficiently.  This fragments your math knowledge so that it becomes to fragile in exams.

Comment: You are right, I need to make maths fun for me. Maybe some recreational maths will do it for me. I'll try to discover some new things.